# Calling a function from the return statement of a void function

Tags: c++, c++11

If I return a void function from a void function, will that function be called before returning?

example:

```
#include <iostream>
void one ( ) { std::cout << "Hello world.\n"; }
void two ( ) { return one ( ); }
int main ( ) { two ( ); }
```

Will "Hello world." be printed to the screen?

Comment: Don't you have a compiler you can test this with?

Comment: Does this compile without warnings?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It should compile. It's one of the two cases (that I know of) where `void` is special-case treated like a complete type.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Without warnings. I can't see anything that would merit a warning.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf there should be a warning about `void not being ignored as it should` or so on the  `return`.

Comment: [I see, that error is only coming up when I use `int two()`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ecc8bf2192abf75)

Comment: You are not returning a function. I think you should change the title, because it is misleading. You are returning the return value of the function (which happens to be void).

Comment: @tobi303 I changed it. Do you think it's better now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. From N3337 (draft C++11 standard):

> [stmt.return]/3 A return statement with an expression of type
>   `void`can be used only in functions with a return type of *cv* `void`;
>   the expression is evaluated just before the function returns to its
>   caller.

Comment: I was hoping someone would find something in the standard confirming my observation. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, "Hello world." will be printed to the screen, as function `one` is called before function `two` returns.

[image]